# magento setdata custom module

Tags: magento, model, module, magento-1.7

I've got a problem when i want to set data in a custom module, i add a field in my database call "test".

the module is ok, all my other attributes work perfectly.

when i do :

```
 Mage::getModel('point/point')->load(1)->setUrl('test')->save();
```

it's ok, the value is save in the DB but with my new field

```
 Mage::getModel('point/point')->load(1)->setTest('test')->save();
```

nothing... The value isn't saved, i don't know why, i try to create other field in my table and it's the same. It's not the first time i do that usually it's ok.

I use magento 1.7.

If someone have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem, I updated my magento and now it's good. Probably it was a fixed bug.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
cache clear
Mage::getModel('point/point')->load(1)->setData('test','testvalue')->save();
```

Comment: Can you add some comment on why you are suggesting this answer? Commenting your code helps the OP and any other reading your answer to better understand how your solution works

Answer (score 0):

Guys I have faced same problem in my custom module.
I checked this steps and solved the problem

Step1:- check your table Engine type if it's InnoDB than change it to MyISAM and than check.

For More info [Click Here](http://magentoo.blogspot.com/2014/01/error-in-setdata-in-magento.html)